# What's the difference between the following three ToString

Tags: c#, .net, string

```
string ToString();
string ToString(IFormatProvider provider);
string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider provider);
```

Comment: Could you explain your question a little further?

Comment: make the question clearer I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the edit:

```
public override string ToString()
```

provides the simplest formatting; it doesn't allow format specifiers and the culture is implicit. But is is convenient for showing is basic UI controls, or during debugging.

The [2 argument version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable.tostring.aspx) allows a format and culture to be specified, and the IFormattable interface is commonly checked for by things like string.Format, and UI controls that allow the developer to specify a format to use (in particular during data-binding).

The 1-parameter version has no special significance; refer to documentation but in the example you give it seems to just allow the culture to be specified. In most cases I would actually expect a

```
public string ToString(string format)
```

to be more likely,  using the current culture by default (or both to be provided).

Answer (score 0):

(note: the question changed...)

You can *always* override ToString (unless a base-class seals it), so you can usually do *something* - but if you want format specifier support (i.e. a text-based pattern such as "###,000") IFormattable is the route - but you need to provide the implementation yourself. Note that in some cases TypeConverter may help too.

Comment: Any example of the second or third one?

Comment: @user496949 - when I added this they didn't exist. See the other answer.